# Metadata ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am broadcasting via rtmp protocol using ffmpeg and I need to add the "create_time" metadata with a **number**, not a string

```
# generates a string
-metadata create_time=1
```

The command:

```sh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i test.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -b:v 800k -crf 35 -intra-refresh 1 -g 1 -filter:v scale="480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -r 60  -metadata create_time=1543434  -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -f flv "stream-url"
```

Comment: Could you provide some reproducible example of your code? I think it will be hard to help without this aspect.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos updated

Comment: I see you added two tags (`ffmpeg-php` and `python`). Is this related to FFMPEG only or a language-based approach? (And if language-based, you should also provide this)

Comment: @AlexanderSantos it has nothing to do with the writing language, I just need the metadata to be a number

Comment: 1543434 looks like a number to me.

Comment: @llogan  yup, only when broadcasting ffmpeg captures it as the string "1543434"